# Why is it console.log will sometimes print undefined for a variable which has been exported?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

So I'm working in node.js (beginner) and I'm trying to use variables which are in a different script. What I've found is that sometimes the variable comes back as undefined. For instance:

```
//Doesnt like this
var peaches = 'Peaches';
exports.peaches;

// Likes
exports.peaches = 'Peaches'
```

Now, It I require this script, I find that if I use the top method, the printout is 'undefined', whereas using the second method, the printout is 'Peaches'.

This wouldn't affect me too much (since I could just always use the second method), however, when I try to export an array using the second method it prints out as undefined. But the confusing thing is that this only happens when I try to import two arrays (the second will always give 'undefined' yet the other will work. Is this to do with the flow of execution of the program? (So it has time to execute the first script, but not the second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var peaches = 'Peaches';
exports.peaches = peaches;
```

In your first "method" you are not actually exporting anything.

The `exports` variable is just a plain JavaScript object created for each
of your modules.

Comment: Okay this does work, however why is it that this doesn't? 
    
    var arr = new Array();
    arr = getArr(body);
    exports.arr = arr;

Comment: What is `getArr(body)`?

Comment: Its a method which returns an array of strings

Comment: Too little info, mate. Maybe you better start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you want to return any javascript module or Object.
You use the `module.exports` object, `module.exports` is the actual object that is returned when you require that exported module.

The `exports` object which you are using to export,  it's a shorthand "alias" for `module.exports`.

Now, since you have not assigned any object to your `exports` object, it is coming as undefined.

Think of it as this way.

```
object = {
  key1:'value1',
  key2:'value2'
}
console.log(object[key1]) // value1
console.log(object[key2]) // value2
//Now, if you try to access something that is not assigned
console.log(object[key3]) // undefined
```

Same is happening with your exports object,
You have not assigned anything to `exports.peaches`, when you do.

```
exports.peaches //hence undefined while import
```

Instead, do

```
exports.peaches = 'peaches'
```

I hope that make sense!.